# How to detect nick update on discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Wanting to make a bot that prevents other people from updating my nickname by immediately changing it back. How can I make it so the program detects the nick update? Is there an event code I can use? Right now going to attempt to simply view the message and see if it begins with /nick, but not sure if the bot can pick that up. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's the [`on_member_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update) event, you can check with an if statement if the before/after nicks are different.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the on_member_update event like this

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(memberBefore,memberAfter):
    if memberBefore.nick != memberAfter.nick:
        memberAfter.edit(nick = memberBefore.nick)
```

This code will prevent changing of nickname for any user. You can set it for only you by changing the if statement to

```
    if memberBefore.nick != memberAfter.nick and memberBefore.name == YourUsername#1234:
```